# is there any way for multiple where statement in Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, where-clause, guard-clause, function-definition

i tried to write 3-4 where statement in a one function but i get error and couldnt do it , i tried to do something like that :

```
foo x=
| x == foo1 = 5
| x == foo2 =3
| x == foo3 =1
| otherwise =2 
where foo1= samplefunct1 x
      foo2= samplefunct2 x
      foo3= samplefunct3 x
```

I know the code is a bit useless but i just wrote this to give an example about what i mean.

Is there anyone who can help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There shouldn't be an `=` after `foo x`.

Comment: @gspr yea you right sorry about that but , i think it wasnt the real question.

Comment: Also, I suggest that you in the future include any error you get. Simply telling people that you "get an error" is not constructive.

Comment: I'll rollback your edit to the original version because that's what the answers respond to. :)

Answer (score 38):

Remove the `=` after `foo x` and indent your code like

```
foo x
    | x == foo1 = 5
    | x == foo2 =3
    | x == foo3 =1
    | otherwise =2 
    where foo1 = samplefunct1 x
          foo2 = samplefunct2 x
          foo3 = samplefunct3 x
```

and you're fine.

Comment: when i wrote someting like i get an error saying "Syntax error in input (unexpected `=')
"  my where statement part is
 |otherwise = (-1,-1)     
 where rightk = rightCheck area number
              leftk  = leftCheck area number

and when i delete one of the where statements, it runs correctly.

Comment: Are you sure your whitespaces are correct? It's hard to tell what you mean by code "like" mine. What I pasted does not have syntax errors.

Comment: Ah, in that case, it seems your code could very well be quite different from what you pasted above. Including the actual code might help.

Comment: yea i'm sure, i'll post what i wrote in my code now  can you check it's where part ?

Comment: I can't check whitespace/indenting when your code is in a comment. Moreover, are you sure that the syntax error is not elsewhere in the code? Have you checked the line number?

Answer (score 14):

If your indentation is a bit uneven, like this:

```
foo x
 | x == foo1 = 5
 | x == foo2 =3
 | x == foo3 =1
 | otherwise =2 
 where foo1= samplefunct1 x
        foo2= samplefunct2 x
         foo3= samplefunct3 x
```

then indeed, the error message talks about unexpected `=` <sub>(and in the future, please do include full error message in the question body).</sub>

You fix this error by re-aligning, or with explicit separators `{ ; }`, making it white-space–insensitive:

```
foo x
 | x == foo1 = 5
 | x == foo2 =3
 | x == foo3 =1
 | otherwise =2 
 where { foo1= samplefunct1 x ;
        foo2= samplefunct2 x ;
          foo3= samplefunct3 x }
```

This runs fine (not that it is a nice style to use). Sometimes it even looks even to you, but isn't, if there are some ***tab characters*** hiding in the white-space.

Answer (score 12):

This code is almost right, you just need the correct indentation: Whitespace matters in haskell. Additionally, using an `=` after `foo` is an error with guards, so you'll have to remove that as well. The result is:

```
foo x
  | x == foo1 = 5
  | x == foo2 =3
  | x == foo3 =1
  | otherwise =2 
  where foo1= whatever1 x
        foo2= whatever2 x
        foo3= whatever3 x
```

Comment: thanks but i want to use 3 different functions in each where statement.As you can see from my code the first where is running with samplefunc1 and the second is running with samplefunct2 and so on, are u sure it is okey with that ?

Comment: yes, I just used `id` so it compiled, it doesn't matter what you stick there